# Android annotation not understood properly

Tags: java, android, annotations

I have been given a project that I have to study & understand. There's a class that has the following: -

```
public abstract class AbstractPayment extends GodelCheckout {
    public static final String AUTH_USING_GET = "GET";
    public static final String AUTH_USING_POST = "POST";

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @StringDef({AUTH_USING_GET, AUTH_USING_POST})
    public @interface AuthMethod {}
```

I tried understanding annotation & why they are important from Google's Developer site, but I couldn't understand much apart from the fact that they are used for improving code.

1. But how are they improving code? Any example?
2. Why is `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)` required here?
3. What does `@StringDef()` actually do?
4. what is `public @interface AuthMthod{}`?
5. Please explain what `Retention.SOURCE, .CLASS & .RUNTIME` really are? I tried understanding them from Google's Developer's site, but it didn't help much?

Comment: 5. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html

Comment: 4. It's an [annotation type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html).

Comment: 1. Some example uses are here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/index.html

Comment: They really helped..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. By marking a function argument or result of it, you can define an expected behaviour. For example it marking a function argument with that annotation, no other argument than `AUTH_USING_GET` or `AUTH_USING_POST` can be passed.
2. With source retention, the code won't compile, when there are annotation errors. After successful compilation, they are removed from code. With retention policy `RUNTIME` the code is inspected during running.
3. `@StringDef` allows you to pass only `String` id's, for example `R.string.login`. `@IntDef` allows you to pass only `R.id.sample_int` to the function
4. This is the annotation, that desired parameters or function results or class fields must be annotated to obtain desired result.
5. Look at second question.

For more questions refer to Java documentation.